# Finding a specific label in ListView when there are multiple values of the same label

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Basically I am making an all product page and I need the id of the specific item so that when the item is clicked it will direct to the specific item's page.
Right now I am facing the problem that I can only access 1 item because the code will always take the first value of the label

```
    foreach (ListViewItem item in ListView1.Items)
    {
        Label mylabel = (Label)item.FindControl("Product_IDLabel");
        string prodID = mylabel.Text;
        Response.Redirect("ProductPage.aspx?ProdID=" + prodID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your looping through the entire Items collection, not just the item(s) that the user clicked on. Are you sure you don't want to be doing this client side, using Html.ActionLink to redirect the user when the .change event is triggered on the listbox?

Comment: Also, are you using web forms or MVC? (I'm guessing web forms?)

Comment: I am using web forms , I dont really understand the html.ActionLink command from my google search it seems to be used in mvc? could you explain in more detail please :/

Comment: See my anwer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45221700/c-sharp-repeater-with-a-varying-number-of-rows-each-able-to-return-a-different-s). It might guide you in the right direction.

Comment: That you very much VDWWD I got it working with command now :D